A question about NON regular sequence of homogeneous polynomials
Let $k = \mathbb{C}$, and define $k[X] = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, where $\deg x_i = 1$. By definition, a sequence of homogeneous elements $f_1, \dots f_r \in k[X]$, where $r \leq n$, is called a regular sequence if $f_i \in k[X]/(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1})$ is  regular (= non-zero-divisor) for any $i = 1,\dots,r$.
In understanding this definition, I came up with this question

Question. If $f_1, \dots f_r$ have the same degree, and $f_1, \dots f_r \in k[X]$ is NOT a regular sequence. Then we know $f_r \in k[X]/(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1})$ is not regular. I am wondering is it true that there always exists an element $0 \neq a \in k[X]/(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1})$ such that $af_r = 0$ in $k[X]/(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1})$ and $a \neq 0$ in $k[X]/(f_1, \dots, f_{r-1}, f_r)$？

I calculated many examples (mainly in the case when $k[X]$ has three variables), and I did not find any counterexample. For instance, let $f_1 = x^2, f_2 = y^2, f_3 = z(x+y) \in k[x,y,z]$. Then $a = x-y$ satisfies $a f_3 = 0 \in k[x,y,z]/(f_1,f_2)$ and $a$ is nonzero in $k[x,y,z]/(f_1,f_2,f_3)$.
In my opinion, to solve the question is manly to answer the following

Can we always choose $a$ such that $a$ is not an element in the ideal $(f_r) \subset k[X]$ generated by $f_r$?

However, I failed to answer the above question, it is more intricate than I think.
Can anyone tell me whether this question is right or wrong, or give me some ideas to prove it. Thank you in advance!

What do you mean by a regular element of a ring and where did you find this definition of a regular sequence? Compare with https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LF.

@Sasha ''Regular element'' I used here is equal to the definition ''not a zero divisor''. I see this definition of regular element in some papers and in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor  I think the regular sequence I mentioned here is same to the link you provide except for the additional condition $r \leq n$. I add condition $r \leq n$ for convenience, maybe I should better exclude it from the definition.

Here is a simple example: $f_1 = x^2$, $f_2 = x$ in $\Bbbk[x,y]$.

Thanks for the example! But it does not answer my question. Since $f_1, f_2$ do not have the same degree here.
